# Make my subclassed UIView have a clear background

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

I have a very simple subclass of UIView with the following:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
    CGContextRef context= UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetAlpha(context, 0.5);
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, CGRectMake(0,0,self.frame.size.width,self.frame.size.height));
}
```

but the background of the image is black when I add it to my `UITableViewCell`'s imageView. Is there any way I can make the background around this circle clear?

Also, the way I am getting `cell.imageView` to be shown is to add a smaller image to `cell.imageView.image` since without it, the `imageView` isn't showing up. Is there any way to fix that as well?

Comment: did you try [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]]; ?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you're asking, but try to set ```self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]```.

Comment: That worked, thanks! Anyone know part two of my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.you should set

```
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor].
```

in your init.
 and then set clear color to fill.

```
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor clearColor].CGColor);
```

the most important step:

```
CGContextFillRect(context,self.bounds);
```

have try.

Answer (score 0):

Before you do any of your drawing operations on the context do:

```
CGContextClearRect(context, rect);
```

Comment: Did not seem to work.